# How can I turn a floor lamp, that emits light upward, into a reading light?

Tags: optics, electricity, everyday-life, reflection

How can I turn this [floor lamp](https://www.flickr.com/photos/89150487@N02/8121062934/sizes/l/) into a reading light? I want all light exiting upwards from the lamp shade to point down.

Do I just buy a mirror and put it on top of the lamp shade? Then the mirror can reflect down any light. But is this safe? I use a fluorescent light bulb, but it still heats up! I don't want a fire hazard.

[image]

This isn't my post, but I forgot where I happened upon it...https://www.doityourself.com/forum/, https://www.house-improvements.com/forums/, or https://www.diychatroom.com/.

Comment: Possibly, a mirror (or shiny white surface) placed on top of the lamp cover to reflect the light back downwards will be the fastest and easiest improvement for now.

Comment: Try to bend the light by prism/inclined mirror to prevent heating up then use parabolic mirror to focus it on your work

Comment: The upward light is not wasted. It is reflecting and diffusing from your ceiling.  A mirror may not help as much as you imagine over the general diffuse light you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first measure - take off lamp coating, which diffuses light. Then put some parabolic mirror bent over lamp, which would give a light directional boost into your book.